# Ajax to submit form and retrieve the url

Tags: php, ajax

i'm on this for hours and i cant figure this out, so please help.

what i want to do is submit form in index.php using ajax to upload.php and retrieve the uploaded file URL so i can show thumbnail.

Then below the thumbnail, again form should appear to upload another image. this should continue three times. because images are limited to three. thumbnails should remain till the end. (please see the image)

[image]

my index.php

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

my upload.php

```
<?php
$target_dir = "data/temp/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/data/temp/". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by Ajax.... JavaScript inside of direct unloading you file image do this by Ajax using JavaScript
And from server side echo your url it will send back to your client side page where using JavaScript you can show the thumbnail if you didn't understand and 
If you need detail code then ask me

```
//First add id to form like formid
//Next code
var formid = document.getElementById('formid');
   fileToUpload = new FormData(formid);
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest ();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("img_id").innerHTML = this.responseText;//here img_id is id for img element where you want to show thumbnail
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "upload.php", true);// if you want to send by get method then write get inside of post
  xhttp.send(fileToUpload);

// Important !!!! form php page echo complete location of thumbnail
```

Comment: please tell me.

Comment: Ok I will send you. I am new on stack overflow can please tell me how to add code format here